# Why are phones not getting charged when I supply 5 V and 0.3 A?

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, battery

I'm using thermoelectric module to get the voltage. With the help of it, I'm getting 3 volts Open circuit voltage. I've attached DC-DC converter which regulates this voltage to 5 volts. I've attached USB at the output of the converter to connect my phone for charging. The thing is a basic cell phone is getting charged some 20% and then it doesn't progress even after 2 to 3 hours of connecting to USB. And whenever I connect smartphone, for a second charging symbol pops up and then charging stops.

Comment: Do you know how much current the thermoelectric module is generating? Can you share the specification of the thermoelectric module and your DC-DC converter.

Comment: 0.3 A is quite small. Most chargers I see are 1 to 2 A

Answer (score 0):

Then the phone charge circuit is not measuring enough capacity of either voltage or current to stay engaged.

Solution is to make sure that the voltage does not drop under load and that sufficient current is available. Some phones need to see 2A available, but will only use what they need of that.

Comment: All phones that use MicroUSB for charging will charge fine on 500mA 5V. Most can utilize 2A if available, but they are required by the standard to accept 500mA without fuss. 300mA available will mean voltage drop such that charging will stop though.